# vector as output for matlab function

Tags: matlab, vector, kalman-filter

I am new to Matlab.

I am doing Extended Kalman Filter simulation which requires calculating Jacobians(partial differenciation functions) for a given function. I am using a function to get the Jacobian values:

```
function [H] = jacobH(x1,x2)
H = [ -(2*x1(1,:,:) - 2*x2(1,:,:))/(8*pi*((x1(1,:,:) - x2(1,:,:))^2 + (x1(3,:,:) - x2(3,:,:))^2)^(3/2)), 0,
      -(2*x1(3,:,:) - 2*x2(3,:,:))/(8*pi*((x1(1,:,:) - x2(1,:,:))^2 + (x1(3,:,:) - x2(3,:,:))^2)^(3/2)), 0];
end
```

The Jacobian basically differenciates 1/(4*pi*sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)) wrt x,y

Eg, If I am passing jacobH(x1(:,1,1), x2(:,1,1)) then I should get H as a 1x4 matrix with [value1, 0, value2, 0]. value1 and value2 varies for different inputs.

But I am getting only one value. I don't know where I went wrong.

I searched for similar questions but none of them are relevant to my issue.

Also, Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: are you supposed to write your own function? Because if you have the symbolic toolbox, you could just as well use the built-in function `jacobian`, which gives you a nice symbolic expression (which you can of course convert to a numerical one if you wish).

Comment: you mean to say you are getting H as a single value rather than a 1x4 matrix ?

Comment: @articuno yes, When I am trying to call the function in another program, I am getting a single value

Comment: just to clarify, by same value I mean, I am getting [value1, 0, value1,0] instead of [value1,0,value2,0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your function I obtain the correct behavior when I try:

```
x1 = ones(3,3,3);
x2 = ones(3,3,3);    
jacobH(x1(:,1,1), x2(:,1,1))

ans =

   NaN     0   NaN     0
```

Comment: @joker thank you for reply. I am however getting a single value result when I try to call my function in another matlab code.

Comment: How does the inputs look like ? Can you post `x1` and `x2` ?

Comment: one sample set of values for x1, x2: x1 = [0,0.5,1,.5;1,0.5,2,.5]' ; x2 = [3,0.7,4,0.7;3.5,0.7,4.75,0.75]' Here both x1,x2 are 4x2x1 matrices. But I am getting [0.0031         0    0.0031         0] i.e same value in H i.e [value1, 0, value1, 0] instead of [value1,0, value2,0]

Comment: ok, in your formula you are basically computing `-2(x1(1)-x2(1))/d` and `-2(x1(3)-x2(3))/d`. In your exemple, as `x1(1)-x2(1) = x1(3)-x2(3) = -3`, it is completely logical to get the same value for the two quantities.

Comment: thank you for that helpful insight! I didnt think it in that way. Also, is there a more elegant way to compute this jacobian?